# How can I export the results of a C# unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Is there a way to export the result of a unit test?

When I run NUnit, can I get formal output saying what methods have been tested and out of those, which one failed and which passed?

Comment: That depends. What test-runner are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the test results to be outputted to a file:

> Redirecting Text Output
>
> Output created by the test, which is normally shown on the console, may be redirected to a file. The following command redirects standard output to the file TestResult.txt:
>
> ```
>   nunit-console nunit.tests.dll /out:TestResult.txt
> ```
>
> The following command redirects standard error output to the StdErr.txt file.
>
> ```
>   nunit-console nunit.tests.dll /err:StdErr.txt
> ```
>
> Note:This option only redirects output produced by the tests, together with selected NUnit output that is interspersed with the test output. It does not redirect all console output. If you want to redirect all output to a file, you should use command line redirection as supported by the shell you are using. This option exists for the purpose of separating test output from other output, such as the NUnit summary report.

From the [NUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3).

I just tested against one of my test assemblies by completing the following steps:

1. Downloaded and installed latest version of [NUnit](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=download)
2. Added 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin' to System Path
3. Navigated to where my assembly was in the command prompt
4. Ran nunit-console MyTests.dll /out:TestResult.txt

The results were then written to TestResult.txt in the same directory.

Comment: `/out:TestResult.txt` give me an error `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter`

Comment: I ran successfully against one of my test DLLs. I updated answer with exact steps I took.

Comment: I have a asp.net web application, what is the dll I have to test? Which folder is it in?

Comment: You should have your unit tests in a separate project. The dll will be built to /YourTestProject/bin/Debug and will be named the same as your project, i.e, YourTestProject.dll